# How do you find out what Firefox Profile is running when Firefox is running?

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

Is there a variable, or an about:config setting, or an add-on that will tell you what Firefox profile you are running when Firefox is running?

So I can come back to Firefox like 3 days later and know that these Windows are for this and those windows are for that...and these plugins are installed in this profile and those plugins are installed in that profile....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Enter `about:profiles` in the URL address bar.

Comment: This answer is correct.  This MDN post has the answer: [`Profile Management`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Multiple_profiles#Profile_management).  You must look for the string: "`This is the profile in use`".  I'd like to know if there is a Javascript value available too though(_???_).

Comment: `about:profiles` doesn't give useful info when firefox is running with a with a tmp profile, `about:support` does

Answer (score 14):

Enter "`about:support`" as URL and select the "`Open containing folder`" button. You can reach it using Menu "`Help`"  -> "`Troubleshooting Information`", too:

[image]

(Screenshot by [lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com/5466891/quickly-back-up-your-firefox-profile-with-aboutsupport))

Comment: Hi -- "Application Basics" can imply the active profie from the "Profile directory".  In practice the user can set the profile directory to point anywhere.  I don't think it can be relied upon unless the `about:profiles` shows a unique folder per profie.

Comment: @will - thank you for your comment, you're right. At the time of my answer (8 years ago), `about:profiles` didn't exist yet, it seems that it was [introduced in december 2015](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2978897). Since then, my answer is in fact outdated...

Answer (score 6):

Using FF version 68.0.2, still no good built-in way to see the profile for the current browser session.
The best way I've found is to make an image with the text of the profile name and add about 150px of right padding.  Then go into Add-ons, Themes, and at the bottom is a link to "Build your own theme with Firefox Color" (this takes you to https://color.firefox.com/).
In there I add the Color addon and then select a preset theme and for Custom Background I select the image I created and select "No repeat".  The text then shows in the top right next to the toolbar buttons. 
It's painful to setup because you need to do it for each profile you have but once it's done it works good.

[image: DI-Staging Profile]

Comment: Nice workaround. It's a pity color.firefox.com seems to force all elements of a theme, and I wasn't able to adjust only the background with my custom image. Seemed to theme everything and did not keep the colours for my OS default theme.

Answer (score -1):

There used to be an add-on called Show Profile: it would add your profile name to Firefox in the title bar and in the Taskbar buttons, like 'Ardw:..'.

But Firefox has killed itself by eliminating 90% of all its add-ons with the arrival of vn.57 - with no apparent easy way of re-compiling old add-ons for the new update.

A serious candidate for an MBA case-study.

*(You can, of course, hold yourself back by refusing any Firefox updates in Options and remaining on vn.56.xx  Old add-ons still work, and they can be downloaded by right-clicking on the green 'Add to Firefox' buttons and saving them on your computer as .xpi files. Life's still good in the past. I have on a couple of machines here. One day, old add-ons may work again in the new.)*